# Impact the boiling time on nutritional content

Tags: data-request, medical, food

I am looking for a data set on the impact the boiling time on the nutritional content of the cooked food with as many following fields as possible:

- type of food (e.g., potatoes),
- curve showing the nutriment loss over cooking time, if possible for each nutriment the food contains.